# TestUtils get React element rendered in the "root"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component rendered directly on the "root" (document.body), I want to get this element using TestUtils but I **do not want** to keep a reference to this element. Is there any way to do that?

Basically I want something like this:

```
React.addons.TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(document.body, MyReactClass);
```

But this does not work (passing `null` or `undefined` as the first parameter does not work either). I am left wondering if there is any "root" React Component Tree that I can get a reference to.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for Unit test purpose, you don't need to do that, if you are testing the component `MyReactClass`, just do :

```
const props = {//some mocked props}
const element = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyReactClass {...props}/>);
```

element will contains the element.

Hope I correctly understood your question...

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, the problem I was having is that I was using Meteor and instantiating React components using the Blaze template engine (I don`t actually create the components, Meteor does it for me) hence the question asking for a way to access a root component. I ended up refactoring my code so I instantiated my components manually which is a little inconvenient when mixing Blaze elements with React components.